# Unable to override blue color of <a> link by inheriting from parent <footer>

Tags: css

I am trying to override the blue color of the link in the footer section of my webpage to match the color of the footer in which the link resides using a declaration on a .footer selector but it's not working.

```css
.footer {
  color: #666;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
            &copy; 2016 Wombat Coffee Roasters &mdash; <a href="/terms-of-use">Terms of use</a>
   </footer>
```

The link still appears blue as displayed in this image:
[Final Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U9K3.png)

Comment: It's because the `<a>` styles from the browsers default stylesheet have higher specificity than your `.footer` selector and are keeping their blue color.

Comment: Thank you. But why does the <a> style from the browser have a higher specificity than something that the author wrote, in this case the .footer selector? Isn't the specificity of author style > user agent style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [CSS cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade) sorts according to importance (normal or important) and origin (author, user, or user agent). In ascending order of precedence:

- user agent declarations
- user normal declarations
- author normal declarations
- author important declarations
- user important declarations

> Thank you. But why does the  style from the browser have a higher specificity than something that the author wrote, in this case the .footer selector? Isn't the specificity of author style > user agent style?

You can use a more specific selector to declare a `color` property for links nested in the `<footer>` or give all `<a>` tags `color: inherit` so they inherit the font color of their parent container. Then the link color will change as you expect since they override the user agent declarations. Currently, the user agent stylesheet provided by the browser is keeping the links their default `-webkit-link` blue color due to precedence.

```css
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Either use a selector in your CSS declaration that is more specific to target permalinks in the footer like `.footer a { color: #666 }` or give all `<a>` tags `color: inherit`. Have a look at [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more.

```css
.footer {
  color: #666;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.footer a {
  color: #666;
}

/* OR */

a {
  color: inherit; /* inherit color from parent */
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
            &copy; 2016 Wombat Coffee Roasters &mdash; <a href="/terms-of-use">Terms of use</a>
   </footer>
```

Comment: So does the browser style have higher specificity because the selector a:-webkit-any-link has 1 pseudo class and 1 element i.e. specificity = (0,1,1) while the .footer selector has specificity of (0,1,0) because there is only 1 class and no element?

Comment: @ShubhamGoel Does this help answer your question? The user agent declarations have higher precedence than the author styles. If you targeted the `<a>` tags in the `<footer>` then your author written styles will have higher precedence and the `color: #666` will be applied therefore overriding the browser style. Indeed the specificity calculation is higher but its more because the CSS cascade sorts user agent declarations first. See my answer for the list of precedence and link to Spec.

Comment: I understand the two fixes for this issue that you provided. Thanks. But I dont understand how the precedence for user agent > author? Precedence for author should be > user agent

Comment: @ShubhamGoel Ok great. Feel free to upvote or mark my answer as it accepted if it solved your problem. Have a look at the [CSS Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/cascade.html#cascade) specification link and you will find where it states in what order the cascade sorts stylesheets and WHY it does things this way.

Answer (score 1):

Add this rule:

```
.footer a{
  color: #666;
}
```

'A' tags will override color, unless you specifically target the 'a' element.

If you want to also override the 'visited' color (turns to purple after click), do the following:

```
.footer a, .footer a:visited{
      color: #666;
    }
```

Comment: I haven't explicitly defined the following: a { color:blue;}. So why does the <a> style from the browser have a higher specificity than something that the author wrote, in this case the .footer selector? Isn't the specificity of author style > user agent style?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to extend it to every element, you can use `color: inherit;`:

```css
.footer {
  color: #666;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
   
a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
            &copy; 2016 Wombat Coffee Roasters &mdash; <a href="/terms-of-use">Terms of use</a>
   </footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the CSS, after `.footer` selector just add `.footer a` then it will be ok. Your CSS must look like this-

```
.footer,
.footer a {
     color: #666;
     background-color: #ccc;
     padding: 15px 0;
     text-align: center;
     font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.footer {
  color: #666;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 15px 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

```html
<footer class="footer">
            &copy; 2016 Wombat Coffee Roasters &mdash; <a href="/terms-of-use">Terms of use</a>
   </footer>
```

Comment: weclome to the community. Your answer seems to be a copy from the code of the question. Could you please edit and explain why and how this is an answer?